# OpenGL ES multiple color buffer

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am using a frame buffer, with 2 color attachments. I want to render, in one render call, into both color attachments.

```
layout (location = 0) out vec3 _color;
layout (location = 1) out vec3 _depth;

_color = texture(_colorImage, coord).xyz;
_depth = texture(_depthImage, coord).xyz;
```

I testet my application of the computer, but now i want to use the same on a mobile application, but how can I render in more than one color attachment in OpenGL ES ?

The preferred version would be OpenGL 2.0. But I don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For color attachments you can't render to more than one in OpenGL ES 2.0; the API doesn't support it.

For OpenGL ES 3.0 onwards it works exactly the same as OpenGL Multiple Render Targets.